# If we do not use any specific new feature of spring boot v2 , do we really need to migrate spring boot application from V1.x to 2?

Tags: spring-boot

why I have spend some extra effort to migrate my application if I'm not using new features of latest version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't *have* to upgrade, but I'd say it's worth it for 2 reasons:

1. Performance and security upgrades of Spring and other dependencies is always a worthwhile effort in my opinion. By skipping upgrades you could be using vulnerable packages.
2. What happens in a year if you *do* need a new feature or need to migrate to JDK 11 and beyond? It's typically easier to do the incremental updates multiple times per year rather than a big-bang upgrade every couple of years.